# Calculating across multiple large dataframes in R

Tags: r, for-loop

I have a set of 6 large matrices, each with the same number of columns (all currently labelled differently) and the same number of rows (all labelled the same way). I want to run some calculations across dataframes to create a new matrix.

I want to run the following calculation: for `n` rows in `df1$[,1:i]`, `sqrt(n)` and add to the values from all equivalent cells in the other 5 matrices.

So if I have two sample matrices such as:

```
 library(tibble)
 df1 <- tribble("Value", ~A, ~B, ~C, ~D,
      "A", .34, .12, 1, 0,
      "B", .89, .2, 0, 0,
      "C", 1, .37, 1, .02,
      "D", 0, 0, .21, 0)

 df2 <- tribble("Value", ~A, ~B, ~C, ~D,
      "A", .21, 0, 1, 0,
      "B", .54, .72, 0, 1,
      "C", .21, .7, 0, 0,
      "D", .45, .03, 0, .12)
```

I want to take a square root of each value for each row in `df1$A` and add it to the equivalent value in `df2$A`, to create a new matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `data.frame`s (or `tibble`s) together:

```
sqrt(df1[, -1]) + sqrt(df2[, -1])

          A         B         C         D
1 1.0413528 0.3464102 2.0000000 0.0000000
2 1.6782450 1.2957417 0.0000000 1.0000000
3 1.4582576 1.4449363 1.0000000 0.1414214
4 0.6708204 0.1732051 0.4582576 0.3464102
```

I also changed your data from `"Value"` to `~Value`:

```
df1 <- tribble(~Value, ~A, ~B, ~C, ~D,
               "A", .34, .12, 1, 0,
               "B", .89, .2, 0, 0,
               "C", 1, .37, 1, .02,
               "D", 0, 0, .21, 0)

df2 <- tribble(~Value, ~A, ~B, ~C, ~D,
               "A", .21, 0, 1, 0,
               "B", .54, .72, 0, 1,
               "C", .21, .7, 0, 0,
               "D", .45, .03, 0, .12)
```

Comment: Brilliant - thank you! Please could you explain what the [, -1] is doing to the code?

Comment: It removes the first column. Since the first column is a character, we remove it because ```"A"+"B"``` does not work